Electron BrowserWindow disable zoom
how can I disable zoom for an electron app? I tried this snippet but it does not work. I can still zoom content with CMD+/-  . Do i need to disable anything else?
const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 1000,
    title: "MyApp",
    resizable: false, // Prevent resizing
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
      contextIsolation: true,
      enableRemoteModule: false,
      webSecurity: true,
      zoomFactor: 1,
      disableZoom: true,
    },


window.webContents.on("before-input-event", (event, input) => {
  if (
    (input.control || input.meta) && // Control for Windows/Linux, Command (meta) for macOS
    (input.key === "+" || input.key === "-" || input.key === "0")
  ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(`Blocked zoom action: ${input.key}`);
  }
});

this blocks keyboard zoom commands and solved it
